# Office 365 ADFS authentication not working for child domains

Tags: active-directory, microsoft-office-365, adfs

A company is using Office 365 with ADFS authentication; AD Connect is used for directory synchronization, ADFS is the Windows server 2012 R2 version.

The company has multiple Active Directory domains:

```
parent1.com
    child1.parent1.com
    child2.parent1.com
    child3.parent1.com
parent2.com
    ...
...
```

The root domains are configured as federated domains in Office 365 (the public domain names and the AD domain names are identical); this works fine, users can login to Office 365 using their UPN, such as `user1@parent1.com`, and their AD password.

I need to add support for child domains; thus I added `child1.parent1.com` to Office 365 by running the following command (after connecting to Office 365 with an admin account using `Connect-MsolService`):

```
New-MsolFederatedDomain -DomainName child1.parent1.com -SupportMultipleDomain
```

(N.B. If I didn't use the `SupportMultipleDomain` parameter, PowerShell would give an error stating it was required).

Then I proceeded to add all required DNS records, both in the private and public DNS; Office 365 validation of DNS records reported everything was ok.

The child domain was then added to AD Connect, and synchronization was performed; users from the child domain thus appeared in Office 365, with usernames such as `user1@child1.parent1.com`. I assigned appropriate licenses to them and tried to login to the Office 365 portal.

However, users for the child domain are unable to login; they receive an "invalid request" error, with the following additional details:

```
Correlation ID: b1e47d45-b21c-42e9-9758-265804db7171 
Timestamp: 2016-08-10 20:27:48Z 
AADSTS50107: Requested federation realm
object 'http://child1.parent1.com/adfs/services/trust/' does not exist.
```

There's obviously something wrong on the ADFS side, but I'm not an expert on it and I also wasn't the one who set it up; how can I fix this so that users in child domains can successfully login to Office 365?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is very scarcely documented ([a Technet blog post](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/abizerh/2013/02/05/supportmultipledomain-switch-when-managing-sso-to-office-365/) and [some documentation for Azure AD](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/active-directory-aadconnect-multiple-domains/)), but it indeed exists, and it's caused by ADFS not behaving correctly in certain specific situations (multiple top-level federated domains and throwing federated child domains in the mix); the solution involves editing a regular expression in an ADFS claim rule which is used to build the IssuerUri associated with the user's UPN. Quoting from the second article:

```
So lets say for example that I have bmcontoso.com and then add
corp.bmcontoso.com. This means that the IssuerUri for a user from
corp.bmcontoso.com will need to be http://bmcontoso.com/adfs/services/trust.
However the standard rule implemented above for Azure AD, will generate a
token with an issuer as http://corp.bmcontoso.com/adfs/services/trust
which will not match the domain's required value and authentication will fail.
```

To solve the issue, the third claim rule in ADFS should be edited, going from

```
c:[Type == "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/claims/UPN"] => issue(Type = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2008/06/identity/claims/issuerid", Value = regexreplace(c.Value, ".+@(?<domain>.+)","http://${domain}/adfs/services/trust/"));
```

to

```
c:[Type == "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/claims/UPN"] => issue(Type = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2008/06/identity/claims/issuerid", Value = regexreplace(c.Value, "^((.*)([.|@]))?(?<domain>[^.]*[.].*)$", "http://${domain}/adfs/services/trust/"));
```

**However, beware that this might break compatibility with other scenarios, such as an actual third-level federated domain whose parent domain is not federated.**